# Read Image from Outside server in java

Tags: java, url, inputstream

I need to display an image in a jlabel Image icon when entering the search of a person, I had the intention to do it by URL, since it reads me the images of the local host, but when trying to read the server that I have above this gives me a "file not found exception" or the known error code "404", I am more than sure that the address of the image in question is fine, but I do not know why it does not work if someone can help me. I would really appreciate it.
I attach the code that I have

```
 try {
            URL url = new URL("http://999.99.99.9/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/img/acm/id157010603.png");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            System.out.println("code:"+conn.getResponseCode());
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();         
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int n;          
            while ((n = is.read(buf)) >= 0) 
                os.write(buf, 0, n);
            os.close();
            is.close(); 
            conn.disconnect();
            byte[] data = os.toByteArray();
            this.binaryImage = data;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

PD: the ip:999.99.99.9 its only for one example.

Comment: Did you include the port in our url?

Comment: [Many similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+read+file+from+network+site:stackoverflow.com). Please check the link.

Comment: i try it with port , but have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path `/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/img/acm/id157010603.png` is where the image you are trying to get is located on the server file system. Tomcat exposes this resource to the world without giving its internal path. You probably can access it using the following url:

`http://999.99.99.9/img/acm/id157010603.png`

Comment: thank you very much!!! I can not believe I did not see that before, I've been doing this for 1 day and it was so obvious ...
really thank you very much